# Pulling Unique Products Bought by One Customer Compared to Another

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, aggregate-functions, having-clause

I have been asked to display a list of products purchased by customers in Germany that were not purchased by customer in the US. After trying to conceptualize how I would structure this, I seemed to have hit a road block.

I wrote a query to provide me all orders placed by both countries (USA and Germany), alongside what products were bought in the order (Ordered by OrderID). Through excel, I was able to find the one product that a Germany customer had bought that a US customer has not bought, but I want to know how to create a query that would provide me that result without needing to use excel. I have attached an image link of the query ran and the results of the query, alongside the tables and columns in the tables (located on the left of the pictures, Customers/Orders/Products).

For reference, I am also utilizing the public Northwind Trader's database for my educational learning.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post your query, sample data, table structure as formatted text - not images which we cannot copy and paste out (and which are a pain to view). For a fast response provide DDL/DML to setup the test data.

Comment: This problem is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64686164/selecting-rows-from-a-table-with-specific-values-per-id). GMB gave you the aggregate option - in the link i wrote a very different one using EXCEPT. Set operators can be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your current query, that brings all products ordered by German and US customers, you can `group by` product, and use a `having` clause to filter on products that were ordered by German customers only.

```
select p.productname, p.productid
from products p
inner join orderdetails od on od.productid = p.productid
inner join orders o        on o.orderid = od.orderid
inner join customers c     on c.customerid = o.customerid
where c.country in ('Germany', 'USA')
group by p.productname, p.productid
having min(c.country) = max(c.country) and min(c.country) = 'Germany'
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and simplest way to do this is by using EXCEPT
Example

First you need products not purchased in USA: you can get this by removing the products purchased in USA from the list of all products

```
    SELECT Products
     FROM ProductsTABLE
   EXCEPT
     SELECT Products
     FROM OrderProductsTable
     WHERE Country = USA
```

Second you need to find if any of the above products are purchased in Germany:

```
SELECT Products 
FROM OrderProducts
Where Country like 'Germany'
AND Prodcuts in (put the code from first step here).
```

You might have to join orders table, country table and products table wherever necessary.